# Linq Include/Exclude logic

Tags: c#, linq

I have an include list containing Name and TypeId, and I want to create an exclude list from it for a given item with some TypeId. but the catch is if a Name does not appear in the list at all then it is not excluded from any type.

How do I do this with linq?

```
       List<NameTypeFilter> includeList = new List<NameTypeFilter>();
        includeList.Add(new NameTypeFilter
        {
            Name = "N1",
            Type = "T1"
        });


        MyItem myItem1 = new MyItem();
        myItem1.Type = "T1";

        MyItem myItem2 = new MyItem();
        myItem1.Type = "T2";

        MyItem myItem3 = new MyItem();
        myItem1.Type = "T3";

        //  excludelist for myItem1 should contain nothing
        //  excludelist for myItem2 should contain N1
        //  excludelist for myItem3 should contain N1

        includeList.Add(new NameTypeFilter
        {
            Name = "N2",
            Type = "T2"
        });

        //  excludelist for myItem1 should contain N2
        //  excludelist for myItem2 should contain N1
        //  excludelist for myItem3 should contain N1,N2
```

Comment: Please show some minimal example describing the problem.

Comment: You iterate over your list and check for that name. If it is not present you return an empty list. If it is present you filter your include list by the TypeId.

Comment: Added example code

Answer (score 0):

If you  share sample of your code it will help to understand your query in more details 
However as per my assumption  if you add Linq condition with TakeWhile or SkipWhile of Linq it may help you get desire results

Answer (score 0):

```
includeList.Where(y => !includeList.Any(z => z.Type == currentItemType && y.Name == z.Name))
```

I think this does it